# Put GLib.Array in a GLib.Value?

Tags: glib, vala

I can't figure out how to wrap a GLib.Array in a GLib.Value.

I tried this code.

```
public int main (string[] args) {
  var value = Value(typeof (Array));

  var a = new Array<string>();
  a.append_val("test");
  value.set_object((Object) a);

  return 0;
}
```

But it resulted in these errors.

```
(process:1797): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid uninstantiatable type '(null)' in cast to 'GObject'
(process:1797): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_set_object: assertion 'G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed
```

Answer (score 1):

I think of GValue being used as a container for a single type of value, whereas GArray is a collection. GValue does have a `type_compatible ()` method. Using that method as a check before your code shows GLib doesn't allow a GArray to be stored as a GObject:

```
public int main (string[] args) {
  if (!Value.type_compatible (typeof (Array), typeof (Object))) {
    message ("Incompatible types");
    return 1;
  }

  var value = Value(typeof (Array));

  var a = new Array<string>();
  a.append_val("test");
  value.set_object((Object) a);

  return 0;
}
```

This code stops where the check for compatible types is made.

I don't know what you are trying to achieve, but I suggest looking at GVariant:

```
void main () {
    string[] a = {"test"};
    Variant variant = a;
    print (variant.print(true) + "\n");
}
```

If you need a GValue then you can store a GVariant in a GValue using GValue's `take_variant ()` method.

Comment: I'm trying to map a `a(ss)` GLib.Settings to my configuration object. The `SettingsBindGetMappingShared` function passes a GLib.Value to set the prop. I was planning to use a GLib.Array of Structs.

Answer (score 1):

`GArray` is not a `GObject`. However, it is a [boxed type](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Boxed-Types.html) (a more primitive version of type tagging used in `GValue`), so you should be able to store it in the `GValue` using `value.set_boxed (a)`.